# Sudo and startup script

Tags: scripts, startup, sudo

I have a new asus 1215n and I need to digit commands to enable multitouch.
No problem: I've made a script.
Since this netbook also need manual activation of the wifi driver the complete script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# list of synaptics device properties http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html#sect4
# list  current synaptics device properties: xinput list-props '"SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"'
#
sleep 5 #added delay...
xinput set-int-prop "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Device Enabled" 8 1
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=32 "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure" 4
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=32 "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Width" 9         #  Below width 1 finger touch, above width simulate 2 finger touch. - value=pad-pixels
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8  "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Edge Scrolling" 1 1 0       #  vertical, horizontal, corner - values: 0=disable  1=enable
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=32 "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Jumpy Cursor Threshold" 250 #  stabilize 2 finger actions - value=pad-pixels
#xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8  "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Tap Action" 0 0 0 0 1 2 3   # pad corners rt rb lt lb tap fingers 1 2 3 (can't simulate more then 2 tap fingers AFAIK) - values: 0=disable 1=left 2=middle 3=right etc. (in FF 8=back 9=forward)
xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8  "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling" 1 0   #  vertical scrolling, horizontal scrolling - values: 0=disable 1=enable
#xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8  "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Circular Scrolling" 1
#xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8  "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" "Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger" 3

sudo modprobe lib80211
sudo insmod /home/pitto/Drivers/broadcom/wl.ko


exit
```

I've saved the script, then put it in my home, then

chmod +x scriptname

and then added it to startup applications.

Then I did: `sudo visudo` and added this row:

```
myusername   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/scriptname
```

rebooted and...

Multitouch works but wifi not.
When I manually launch the script it asks for sudo password so I thought it was because of modprobe and insmod commands and I've added those commands to sudo visudo.
Nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The modprobe / insmod commands should be placed into /etc/rc.local without sudo (rc.local is invoked during startup, with root).

Comment: Did you check dmesg for any errors regarding wifi?

Comment: Thank you mates... /etc/rc.local did the trick! Absolutely no error regarding wifi: if I insert the sudo password it works great but I would like it to work without inserting password

Comment: Thanks Stefano for editing!
If you teach me the right tag to send scripts I'll do better next time :)

Comment: If you use the ``` character before and after a piece of text, it will be formatted as code. For longer code snippet, simply make sure they're indented with at least four spaces. For more information have a look at the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help). @Pitto

Comment: No backtick on Italian keyboard...
I'll copy/paste it... Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right `/etc/sudoers` configuration to prevent prompting for password is:

`myusername ALL = NOPASSWD: /home/scriptname, /sbin/modprobe lib80211, /sbin/insmod /home/pitto/Drivers/broadcom/wl.ko`

Comment: I've corrected it but it keeps asking me the password :/

Comment: You have to add the `/sbin/modprobe` and `/sbin/insmod` applications to the `NOPASSWD` line in `/etc/sudoers` too. It would be a security risk otherwise.